# Python/Django date query: Unsupported lookup 'date' for DateField or join on the field not permitted

Tags: python, django, date

I have a simple method. Entries are entries in a time sheet application where employees enter their hours.

```
class Entry(m.Model):
    """ Represents an entry in a time_sheet. An entry is either for work, sick leave or holiday. """
    # type choices
    WORK     = 'w'
    SICK     = 's'
    VACATION = 'v'
    type_choices = (
        (WORK,     'work'),
        (SICK,     'sick leave'),
        (VACATION, 'vacation'),
    )
    # meta
    cr_date = m.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False, verbose_name='Date of Creation')  # date of creation
    owner   = m.ForeignKey(User, editable=False, on_delete=m.PROTECT)
    # content
    type    = m.CharField(max_length=1, choices=type_choices, default='w')
    day     = m.DateField(default=now)
    start   = m.TimeField(blank=True)  # starting time
    end     = m.TimeField(blank=True)  # ending time
    recess  = m.IntegerField()  # recess time in minutes
    project = m.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=m.PROTECT)

    @classmethod
    def get_entries_for_day(cls, user, day):
        """ Retrieves any entries for the supplied day. """
        return Entry.objects.filter(day__date=day, owner=user).order_by('start')
```

However, when I try to run my project like this, it terminates with the following error code:

> "Unsupported lookup 'date' for DateField or join on the field not
>   permitted."

I don't quite understand the message. The specified field is a date field which has no further restrictions. Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with `day__date=day`?  The double-underscore syntax is meant to express a parent-child relationship, i.e. that the `day` field has a subfield named `date`.

Comment: See my comment below, I found it in the django documentation as a means of checking for a date in queries.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's no such thing as a `__date` lookup on a DateField; the field is already a date.

It's not clear what you are trying to compare this field with. Is the day you are passing into that method an integer, or a date? If it's also a date then you should just compare them directly.

Comment: I found __date in the Django documentation. I'm running Django 1.9 and it's a new feature: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#date  This is the example they provide:  
    Entry.objects.filter(pub_date__date=datetime.date(2005, 1, 1))  
The local variable that I'm passing to the method is this:  
    day  datetime.date(2016, 6, 1)

Comment: So I have been messing around with it a bit. Comparing directly works with:  
    return Entry.objects.filter(day=day, owner=user)  
When I tried that before, I got no results from the database when I should have. So I thought that maybe it didn't bring any results because I was trying to compare objects in the wrong way or was comparing different objects to one another and got no results for that reason. However, the question remains: what is the query argument '__date' good for? Maybe that's used when the date is not stored in a date format?

Comment: `__date` is used on DateTimeField, not a DateField, to match on the date portion only.

Comment: Just found that `__date` lookup does not work as expected. I am using Django 3.2.8 and I confirm I am applying this lookup to `DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True, null=True)`. I can use a workaround `__contains` or `__startswith` but still not sure why it does not work. I am using custom timezone.

Answer (score 1):

I'm facing an issue with Django-filters, The filter was not taking the same date range while I was using it. so I added `date__lte/gte` in `lookup_expr.something` like this.

```
from_date = django_filters.DateFilter(field_name="created_at", lookup_expr='date__gte')
to_date = django_filters.DateFilter(field_name="created_at", lookup_expr='date__lte')
```